# OS X El Capitan: Connected to Wi-Fi / Personal Hotspot network but not connected to Internet

Tags: macos, mac, network, wifi, internet-sharing

I recently updated to El Capitan.

But now when connection is established with my college's Wi-Fi network I am unable to use internet. Same goes for Personal Hotspots.

Everything was working fine in Yosemite.

**How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a new network location. Network Preferences/edit top drop down/new location/apply If that doesn't work you may need to reinstall OS to resolve software issue.

Answer (score -1):

See if you set a wrong DNS address in system preferences -> network